# Run a coroutine in the background from a non-async function

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Here is a simplified version of what my code is doing, hope it is self-explanatory enough.

```
def config_changed(new_config: Any):
    apply_config(new_config)
    start()
    asyncio.create_task(upload_to_db({"running": True}))

async def upload_to_db(data: Any):
    await some_db_code(data)

def start():
   asyncio.create_task(run())

async def run():
   while True:
       do_something_every_second()
       await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
some_db_client.listen_to_change(path_to_config, callback=config_changed)
loop.run_forever()
```

The code above runs into an error: `no running loop` at the line `asyncio.create_task(run())`. So I changed all `asyncio.create_task` into:

```
try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
except RuntimeError:
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.create_task(...)
```

Now the task never start running. I confirmed `start` has been called.

I changed `loop.create_task(...)` into:

```
task = loop.create_task(...)
loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

Now it will run, but `upload_to_db` was never called. Seems like the first `run_until_complete` will block the code below it.

What is the correct way of doing this?

I am aware that using threading can probably solve this, but I think this should be solvable without using threading. After all, `asyncio` is to spare us from using threading in this kind of situations right?

**Edit: add more context.**

The reason `start` need to be non-async is because it is a function in an abstract class, in fact, all functions are members of that abstract class, but only `start` is abstract. Some child class may use it to run an async function like my example above, others may use it to run a function that will callback in the future, but itself is not async, for example:

```
def start():
    some_db_client.listen_to_change(path, callback=my_callback)
```

So `start` has to be non-async and use `asyncio.create_task` when the implementation requires async, in order to be compatible with both cases.

If not for that limitation, I can just call

```
asyncio.gather(start(), upload_to_db({"running": True}))
```

Comment: "After all, asyncio is to spare us from using threading in this kind of situations right" - no, not really. asyncio lets async code cooperatively multitask with other async code. If you want to run sync code at the same time, you're going to need multiple threads.

Comment: @user2357112 But isn't it automated behind the scene, like when using asyncio.gather?

Comment: Sounds like you've got some kind of misunderstanding of what asyncio is and how it works, but it's not clear what that misunderstanding might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it perfectly.

```
__coro_queue: asyncio.Queue[Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]] = asyncio.Queue()
__loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop | None = None
__task: asyncio.Task[Any] | None = None
__task_ready = asyncio.Event()

async def start_coro_queue() -> None:
    global __loop, __task
    __loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        coro = await __coro_queue.get()
        __task = asyncio.create_task(coro)
        __task_ready.set()
            
def run_coroutine_in_background(
        coro: Coroutine[Any, Any, Any]) -> asyncio.Task[Any]:
    assert __loop is not None
    __task_ready.clear()
    __loop.call_soon_threadsafe(__coro_queue.put_nowait, coro)
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(__task_ready.wait(), __loop)
    future.result()
    assert __task is not None
    return __task
```

Run this line before running any coroutine.

```
await start_coro_queue()
```

`start_coro_queue()` will never end, so you need to put other code above it, or use gather. In my case:

```
some_db_client.listen_to_change(path_to_config, callback=config_changed)
await start_coro_queue()
```

Every time you need to run a coroutine in the background and get a task object so you can cancel it in the future.

```
task = run_coroutine_in_background(your_coroutine)
```

Basically use it to replace `asyncio.create_task` in my original code.

`run_coroutine_in_background` can be called from a non-async function, it can even be called from a different thread. In my case:

```
some_db_client.listen_to_change(path_to_config, callback=config_changed)
```

calls the callback in a different thread.

Answer (score 2):

That is not how async works.

Async functions will block the current path. They are not doing threading, they do not execute "in the background." However, if you have multiple async functions that are all waiting, you can wait in parallel if you call them all at the same time using some asyncio function. For this type of "concurrency," you need to call the async functions in some way that asyncio knows to call them at the same time. The simplest way is using asyncio.gather, take for example:

```py
import asyncio

async def factorial(name, number):
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, number + 1):
        print(f"Task {name}: Compute factorial({number}), currently i={i}...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        f *= i
    print(f"Task {name}: factorial({number}) = {f}")
    return f

async def main():
    # Schedule three calls *concurrently*:
    L = await asyncio.gather(
        factorial("A", 2),
        factorial("B", 3),
        factorial("C", 4),
    )
    print(L)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This will work, printing in parallel, because `asyncio.gather` will make the functions execute at the same time, and do the waiting in parallel. However, if we would have instead called:

```py
await factorial("A", 2),
await factorial("B", 3),
await factorial("C", 4),
```

They would have executed in order, blocking each other.

You cannot run a coroutine in the background from a non-async function, because that is not how async works. If you have two async functions, and both are waiting in an async-compatible way, you can wait in parallel by calling them with asyncio.gather or similar, but that is all. If you want to do more than that, you need threading.

`create_task()` which you are currently using, is not special in this case. It still waits in parallel if called correctly (for example, if called in one of the async.gather'ed calls in the example above). It simply adds another thing to "wait in parallel" list, without blocking the current async function.

I will say, usually, async is all you need, and the question can be rephrased in the terms of async. However, I don't know your exact use-case, so I cannot do that for you.

I hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've edited my problem to add more context to why `start` need to be non-async and why I can't just call `asyncio.gather(start(), upload_to_db(...))`

Comment: I see.

If you cannot change the fact that some of these are non-async functions, I think you simply need to use threading. I don't see another option. Remember, asyncio originated as a library written in plain python, which later got merged into std. It doesn't do anything special with the interpreter, and it doesn't do anything you couldn't implement as a library yourself.

Comment: Hi, after days of try and error, I found a way to do it perfectly. Check out my answer if you are interested, also let me know is there any potential problems.